# button event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I want this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("bgcTest", "CompaniesController")) 
{
    <p>
        Ange BolagsID: <br />
        <input type="text" name="BolagsID" />
        <input type="submit" value="bgc test" />
    </p>
}
```

To fire this event:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult bgcTest(string BolagsID)
{
     ...
}
```

But I get the error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /CompaniesController/bgcTest

I can't for the life of me figure it out. If I just make an actionlink I get my method to fire, but I need an user inputted variable to go along with the fireing.

What am I doing wrong?

(This is my first time with MVC and I have to implement some functionality into an already existing project. For work.)

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Yessir, edited the title for future readers!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your controller class (.cs file) is `CompaniesController.cs`.
That's a convention (default behavior) where MVC will automatically identify it as a controller.
When referencing this controller in your view, use `Companies` only.
If you use `CompaniesController` MVC will try to find a CS file named `CompaniesControllerController`.

Correct code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("bgcTest", "Companies"))
```

Comment: Cheezus, it was that simple? I feel like a total idiot. Thanks! The answer will be accepted in 8 minutes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we all made this mistake at least once :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm never, I repeat, never, going to make this mistake again! Not after struggling for three hours with it and then getting this answer... :P